# PHP Generate a random amount of a certain character.

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a method to generate a random amount of this character:

```
_
```

On page-refresh I need to generate a random amount of those charactors, so for instance:

```
_______
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just use `rand()` if you want random. Example:

```
$char = '_';
echo str_repeat($char, rand(1,50));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
echo str_repeat("__", mt_rand(1, 50));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = rand(1,100);
$x = 0;
while($x<=$number)
{
    echo '_';
    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) and [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php):

```
echo str_repeat('_', rand(1, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < rand(1,15); $i++) {
    echo '_';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you ?

```
<?PHP

    for($i = 0; $i < rand(10,50); $i++) {
        print "_";
    }

?>
```

Comment: oh, looks like i was beaten to it lol...

Answer (score 0):

```
$char = '_';
echo str_repeat($char, rand(1,50));
```

This solution worked for me in my script, thank you.